# Satzstellung: Reflexives Objekt vor Subjekt?

Tags: word-order

Deutsch ist eine relativ flexible Sprache, wenn es sich um die Satzstellung handelt. Gibt es Fälle, in denen man das reflexive Objekt vor dem Subjekt stellen kann? Zum Beispiel:

> (a1) Darauf freue mich ich.
>
> (a2) Mich freue ich darauf.
>
> (b1) Sicher bin mir ich.
>
> (b2) Mir bin ich sicher.

Sind diese Beispiele richtig, unidiomatisch, oder völlig falsch?

Wenn es nicht um ein reflexives Objekt geht, entsteht kein Problem, wie man im folgenden Satz sehen kann:

> (c) Dir gebe ich ein Buch.

Comment: Ich kenne die entsprechende Regel nicht. Aber alle Sätze klingen für mich als Muttersprachler falsch und erinnern mich entfernt an Meister Yoda aus Star Wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vorbemerkung**

Um wirklich eine Antwort zu erhalten, muss man zunächst mal anfangen in Nebensätzen zu analysieren. Die erste Position in einem Hauptsatz ist eine Art Bonusposition und nicht alles, was im Hauptsatz in der ersten Position ist, kann auch im Nebensatz vorne kommen.

> Gestern war ich im Park.... völlig ok.
>   *Ich weiß, dass gestern ich war im Park.

Die zweite Version ist extrem markiert und wirkt in den allermeisten Kontexten schlicht falsch. Die wahre natürliche Reihenfolge der Elemente eines Satzes sieht man nur in seiner Nebensatzform.

**Zur Frage**

Nun zur Frage, ob ein Reflexivpronomen vor dem Subjekt stehen kann. Die Antwort ist ja.

> …, dass sich meine Frau im Fitnessstudio angemeldet hat.
>   …, dass meine Frau sich …

Das ist beides ok und idiomatisch.
Das ist aber nur der Fall, wenn zwei Bedingungen erfüllt sind.

1. Das Reflexivpronomen muss "echten" Inhalt haben. Man muss es durch ein nicht-reflexives Pronomen ersetzen können, ohne dass sich der Sinn des Verbs selbst stark ändert.

> *..., dass mich ich darauf freue.

Das ist nicht möglich, da schlicht niemand anderes "mich" darauf freuen kann. Das Reflexivpronomen ist pure Grammatik, die durch die Umstellung implizierte Hervorhebung des Subjektes kann nicht "gefüllt" werden. Deshalb klingt es unsinnig.

2. Das Subjekt selbst darf KEIN Pronomen sein. Am besten es ist auch nicht Teil der Konversation gewesen.

> …, dass sich er ein Buch kauft.
>   …, dass ihr er ein Buch kauft.

Beides klingt extrem komisch und viele würden es als falsch bezeichnen (obgleich sich sicher Situationen finden lassen, wo es gesagt wird). Es hat also wenig mit dem Reflexivpronomen zu tun, sondern ist Ausdruck eines allgemeineren Trends.
Zum einen kommt das Subjekt generell sehr oft als Erstes, zum anderen kommen Personalpronomen sehr früh. Die Kombination dieser beiden "Kräfte" führt dazu, dass beim Nachstellen des "er" viel Spannung (und mithin Betonung) entsteht. Die kann das langweilige "er" aber nicht "füllen". Man erwartet was Tolles und kriegt nix.
Direkt falsch klingt es aber wohl vor allem deshalb, weil wir es in dieser Reihenfolge einfach nicht gewohnt sind.

Es gibt allerdings auch Beispiele, wo das Reflexivpronomen sogar vor dem Subjekt kommen MUSS. Eins wurde bereits in diesem Text verwendet.

> …, obgleich **sich** sicher **Situationen** finden lassen, wo es gesagt wird.
>   *…, obgleich Situationen sich sicher finden lassen …

Die zweite Version ist extrem markiert, und da das "sich" rein grammatisch ist, gibt es keinen Kontext, wo diese Umstellung Sinn machen würde.
Der Grund für diese Ausnahme ist, dass hier das Subjekt sehr definierend für das Prädikat selbst ist. Das ist bei den meisten Verben nicht der Fall. Hier aber schon und es ist so wichtig, dass es sogar als Indefinitpronomen hinten findet.

> …, obgleich sich welche (Situationen) finden lassen, …

Nur als Personalpronomen rückt es nach vorne.

> …, obgleich sie sich sicher finden lassen, …

Auch das kann man relativ schlüssig begründen, aber das würde hier zu weit führen.

**TL,DR**

Ja, Reflexivpronomen können unter bestimmten Bedingungen vor dem Subjekt stehen und manchmal müssen sie es sogar.

Answer (score 5):

(a2) betont das Objekt "mich", indem es ins Vorfeld gestellt wird. Aber "freue" und "ich" deklarieren bereits eindeutig die erste Person Singular, die grammatikalisiert ist; es *kann* also kein anderes Objekt geben als das genannte, wodurch die Betonung unsinnig wird. Sinnvoll wäre: "Den Gunnar verdächtige ich der Tat" (denn ich könnte ja auch die Anna verdächtigen).

Ähnlich mit (a1): Auch die Umstellung zwischen "mich" und "ich" hat oft die Funktion, das Subjekt herauszustellen, aber das Subjekt ist zu 100% vorhersagbar und *kann* nicht bemerkenswert sein. Richtig dagegen: "Darüber freut sich der Spießer", denn es könnte sich ja auch der Freigeist freuen.

Mit dem Dativobjekt verhält es sich m.E. genauso.

Answer (score 0):

> (a1') "*Darauf* freue ich mich." - wenn die Sache wichtiger ist.
>
> (a2') "Ich *freue* mich darauf." - wenn das Verb wichtiger ist.

Man muss sich also überlegen, was genau man sagen möchte.

> (b1') <strike>*Sicher* bin mir ich.</strike> - vielleicht ist das möglich, aber es klingt falsch.
>   "Ich bin mir *sicher*." - klingt gut.
>   "*Sicher* bin ich mir nicht." - ist ebenfalls richtig.
>
> (b2') <strike>Mir bin ich sicher.</strike> - klingt ebenfalls seltsam.

[Schau mal hier bei 7. "Satzstellung".](http://www.dsporto.de/ubungen/reflexivregeln.htm)